# C#: overwriting string value in if else statemnt?

Tags: c#

I have a fairly simple if else statement in C# that looks something like this;

```
    string BodyContent = "";
    if (Request.Form["value1"] != "")
    {
        BodyContent = "bla bla 1";

    }

    else if (Request.Form["value2"] != "")
    {
        BodyContent = "bla bla 2";
    }
else if (Request.Form["value3"] != "")
{
    BodyContent = "bla bla 3";
}
else {
    BodyContent = "Error";
}
```

My problem is that even if Request.Form["value3"] does have a value it is the value from BodyContent in the value1 check that is visible. (It can only be one of the request form objects that has a value at any point in time, so it is not because both value1 and value3 has a request.form value)

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your `Request.Form["valueX"] != ""` with `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["valueX"])` and see what that does for you.

Comment: +1. If an entry in the Form array doesn't have a value, it will be null, not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You're running a string of else-ifs, so the first condition that is true will set the variable, and no other condition will be checked. Are you certain the first two conditions are not true?